# How to get host-name from DHCP server via Network Manager?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, networkmanager

I can get hostname and ip address from DHCP server with invoking the script under `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/` directory as explained [here](http://nxhelp.com/blog/2013/1/24/automatically-set-hostname-from-dhcp-in-debian-using-isc-dhcp-client) on client side . But it stopped after installed network manager. I realize that network manager doesn't invoke scripts under `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/` directory. After some research, I found that I can run a script under `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` directory. I tried it (moved file, then gave permissions) but It didnt work. Because I can not reach variables like `$reason, $interface etc.` under that directory. I'm stuck here. So is there a way to get hostname from dhcp server via network manager? or how to run a script under `dhclient-exit-hooks.d` directory on boot even if network manager runs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched about 8 days to find a solution but I found nothing. I developed my own method. It is not the best way but It works.

First step: Ubuntu always shows "Waiting for network configuraion..." and waits 2 minute to pass that. I changed two lines in `failsafe.conf` and disabled "sleep" functions to solve this problem.

```
* sudo nano /etc/init/failsafe.conf

... 
$PLYMOUTH message –text=”Waiting for network configuration…” 
#sleep 40 

$PLYMOUTH message –text=”Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network…”
#sleep 59 
...
```

Second step: Network fails after disable "sleep" functions. I changed `rc.local` to run `/etc/init.d/networking restart` to configure network correctly before login.

```
* sudo nano /etc/init/rc.local

/etc/init.d/networking restart
exit 0
```

I hope it will be useful for someone who faced the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

dhclient hooks script often without shebang at first line but NM hooks need it.
/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/xxxx.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$2" = "hostname" ]; then
  ......
fi
```